# How to convert Android Json String to json object in most efficient way

Tags: android, performance, http-post, android-json

I have following two string with me

```
String macId= "484487E3A0AC",484487E3FG55,484487E3A0FG,484487HJKL90,484487EKLJK9;

String movieList="Cast Away";
```

I want to send it to my server as json Object, I am able to achieve it when I send it as single object :

EX:

```
String macId= "484487E3A0AC";
String movieList="Cast Away";

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.accumulate("title", movieList);
json.accumulate("mac", macId);
httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString()));
httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

finally the json data which I am sending looks like this :

```
{"mac":"484487E3A0AC","title":"Cast Away"}
```

Now I have a requirement where My macId is a list (there might be around 10 macId) , where as the movieList will be same .
What will be the most optimized way to convert it to json object .
Server side coding reads the data as :

```
{"mac":"......","title":"......"}
```

So got to convert it accordingly ,
Please provide some solution as how to club it together

Comment: There's not enough information here - do you want `{"mac":"1,2,3,4,5", "title":"a,b,c,d,e"}` or do you want `[{"mac":"1","title":"a"},{"mac":"2","title":"b"}...]`? If the second, look up [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)  - you want to create an array of objects.

Comment: Hi I want the final out put as--{"mac":["1,2,3,4,5"], "title":"a"}